# JSON, error "Expected :" occurs in IE only

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

There are other threads with this error but none of the solutions apply.

I am receiving error **SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'** in IE only, my website works fine in Chrome and FF. The highlighted section of the below script (second image) is what IE is complaining about. There are 4 scripts that all throw this error in similar place.

**Script**

[image]

[image]

```
             $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                   url: 'explode',
                   data: {'msmm_tn' : '221d8fdee0897e6924791b8f7b5fe70f', link_id},
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success : function(data) {
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, it's not searchable and we can't copy/paste it into answers.

Comment: see if data will be a valid json or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly

```
{key : value, something}
```

is generally not a valid object, it's missing the key and the colon, and should be

```
{key : value, key2 : something}
```

The reason it works in Chrome and FF is because those browsers assume you're trying to use [destructuring assigments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and inserts the key for you, but IE doesn't support that.

Add keys to your objects

```
data : {'msmm_tn' : '221d...', 'link_id' : link_id}
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo, that was the issue.